# Splash for appjs applications

Tags: javascript, appjs

Is it possible to show a splash before opening an appjs application?
I need to show an image before opening the appjs application for 2 or 3 seconds and need to be closed and then need to open the application window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to open more than one window:-

```
var splashWindow = app.createWindow({ 
   width  : 300,
   height : 300,
   icons  : __dirname + '/content/icons',
   resizable: false, 
   url: 'http://appjs/splash.htm'
});
```

So maybe you can open this first window and then connect to servers or preload content and once you are ready you can then open the main application window:

```
var window = app.createWindow({ ... });
```

/Simon